# Don't have permission to access SQL Server Express 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don’t have permission to access SQL Server Express 2008??](https://serverfault.com/questions/53645/dont-have-permission-to-access-sql-server-express-2008)

I have a remote PC with SQL Server 2008 setup and allowing remote connections.

I am an Admin user on the PC and have remotely connected to the SQL Server and I am trying to restore a database from backup but getting permissions denied for anything I try to do on the server!

I can add myself as a login to the SQL database but only with public server roles!

The server is setup to Log in as Local Account and I also have the SQL Server Browser running as well!

What am I doing wrong or missed??

Comment: what's the user you used to connect to sqlserver?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/53645/dont-have-permission-to-access-sql-server-express-2008

Answer (score 1):

Starting from SQL Server 2005 SP2 members of Administrators group are not added to sysadmin role on the server by default in case you're running Windows Vista or higher. Now specifying server administrator(s) is an additional step during SQL Server setup. In case you've missed it, there's a special 'SQL Server provisioning tool' that you can use later to add someone to sysadmin role.